# Router keeps forwarding to different port

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, wordpress

I have a home server where I run my website. My current website is a spring-boot application running on port **8080**. On my router I opened port **80 to 8080**. Everything is working fine with that website.

I wanted to create a new website with WordPress so I [installed](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#1-overview) it on my server and on my router I opened port **82 to 80** so I was able to create my new website while the other one is still running. so when I wanted to visit the WordPress site I would type **[IP]:82** in the browser and work on it.

Once everything was done I closed the **80->8080** port and open **80->80** port to make my WordPress website public.

Now when I type only the **[IP]** or even **[IP]:80** I am forwarded to **[IP]:82** automatically even on different browsers. I can't visit the website since it is running on port **80 not 82**.

I have tried many things and apparently it only works when I open port **82->80**.

Any hints to solve the problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in wp admin page under setting->general I wrote under "WordPress Address (URL)": [IP]:82. so wp was redirecting my requests.